# Laravel 5.1 GeoIP Non-static method should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Tags: php, geolocation, laravel-5.1, geoip

I am using Torann\GeoIP And I am getting this error when I try

```
    use Torann\GeoIP\GeoIP;
Route::get('geoip', function() {
    $location = GeoIP::getLocation();
});
```

but when I try with

```
    $geo = new GeoIP();
$geo - getLogation();
```

I have this error 'Argument 1 passed to Torann\GeoIP\GeoIP::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Config\Repository, none given'

so I am missing the arguments for the __construct ....`$config, $session` 
so it should be looking like this

```
$loc = new GeoIP($config, $session);
$loc ->getLocation();
```

but what do I need to give to $config = ? and $session = ?

Any siggestions will be helpfull. Thank you

If there is better way to get the GeoLocation data it would be great.

Answer (score -1):

You must declare:

```
use Torann\GeoIP\GeoIPFacade as GeoIP;
```

and move the file 
 `/vendor/torann/geoip/src/config/geoip.php` into `/config/geoip.php`.

Comment: Your answer is about configuring GeoIP not about solving the problem!